# servlet and jsp displaying same information?

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

Currently I am trying to display information from my java servlet over to its related jsp page. However, when I run the program, the expected output of the jsp file is displayed in the servlet directory.

Visually, the Display.jsp page:
[image]

And \ServerToRun (The Servlet page that should display a blank screen):
[image]

Thus my question is,

> Why is the content of /Display.jsp appearing in /ServerToRun?

**Here is the code for `doPost()` of the ServerToRun class:**

```
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse 
response) throws ServletException, IOException {

    CSVFileOperations csvfo = new CSVFileOperations();
    String url = "/Display.jsp";

    response.setContentType("text/html");

    String header = csvfo.getHeaders().remove();
    System.out.println(header);

    request.setAttribute("header", header);

    request.getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher(url).
    forward(request, response);


    }
```

**And the markup for Display.jsp:**

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
<title>OTS Grief</title>
</head>

<body>

${header}<br>
Test Why is his showing up in ServerToRun?
</body>
</html>
```

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think I understand your question. You're talking about directories.

In your URL, the path (/Grief_UI/Display.jsp and /Grief_UI/ServletToRun) is not necessary related to folders.

It is a structuring element of the URL. Sometimes you don't even have files that are named like these path elements. The path gets normally processed by a Servlet and the user gets the feeling of using folders, yes, but it is only a description for the localising the resources.

Comment: Sure, but how do I fix this. What do I change in my code, because I still don't really understand what is wrong. As I said in my question, why is the content of Display.jsp appearing when I visit serverToRun?

Comment: HTTP works as following, shortly explained:

1) the client (mostly the browser) sends a request to the server (your servlet container like Tomcat).
2) This request gets processed by a servlet. Let's say your ServletToRun.
3) The servlet writes a response.
4) The response gets back to the browser, which gets displayed.

Comment: So let's say ServletToRun gets the request from the browser. In the lines: 

    String url = "/Display.jsp";
    request.getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher(url);
    forward(request, response);

You're forwarding the control to the Display.jsp.

Now the Display.jsp is writing to the response, which the browser is finally displaying.

That's why they both display the same information.


I don't really understand what's you're up to, so I cannot really tell you what the solution is.

Comment: If the servlet should display nothing (blank), comment out the line forward() and write an empty html to the response: response.write("<html><body></body></html>")

Answer (score 1):

Because from servlet you are redirecting to Display.jsp. Try adding any dynamic content in JSP and execute both, only servlet would be able to display the dynamic content.!

Answer (score 0):

Is because your servlet is trapping all requests, you should notice which annotation you are putting in your ServerToRun.java class or if you are putting in the display descriptor (web.xml) the annotations of the servlet.